# How to clear history on a WebView component?

Tags: ubuntu-sdk

I am writing a small application containing a WebView component. The final app should work in a kiosk setup, so I need to clear everything in between different sessions, in particular the navigation history.
Is this possible in QML at all?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer yet, but I'm making it into a wiki in the hope that someone can complete it.

You may want to look at [QtWebKit.experimental](http://rschroll.github.io/beru/2013/08/21/qtwebview.experimental.html).  If you add `import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0` to your QML files, your WebView objects gain an *experimental* attribute that gives you access to all sorts of super powers.  Of particular interest to you are probably *experimental.navigationHistory.backItems* and *experimental.navigationHistory.forwardItems*, which provide models for the two halves of the navigation stack.  I've never used them, but I did find [this example](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/WebKit2/WebKit2-7536.26.14/UIProcess/API/qt/tests/qmltests/WebView/tst_navigationHistory.qml) that may help.

Unfortunately, the [source](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtwebkit/Source/WebKit2/UIProcess/API/qt/qwebnavigationhistory_p.h.html) seems to indicate that these are read-only objects, so you may not be able to clear them from QML.

Comment: I followed the QtWebKit.experimental path before, but as you noticed the properties are read only, that is, calling reset() on those two ListModels has no effect.